# How to run a script on a server 1 minute after a commit has been made?

Tags: bash, scripting, git, scheduled-task

Apart from creating a 2nd script which would check the time of the last commit and then run the main script and which would be too complex of a solution, is there a simpler one?

Answer (score 4):

Write a git post-commit hook that contains a  call to `at time+60`

Comment: what is "a call to at time+60"?

Comment: @Oaemirami `at` is a command that executes another specified command at a given time (+60 seconds in this case).

Comment: Why not just `sleep 60` instead of using `at`?

Comment: @jwodder Because that would block.

Comment: The request was for script on "a server". If this is the host running the remote repo, this would be the `post-receive` hook.

Comment: @start that would not block if launched in a forked shell

Answer (score 1):

Besides `at` (which may or may not be available to the user under which the hook runs), you can also do something like that from the appropriate hook, probably `post-receive`):

```
( sleep 1m ; /usr/local/bin/do_something ) &
```